# Rails 4 has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models. Venues and Categories. They are related to each other as `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Categories are pre populated and in the form i want to display a multi-select to allow choosing the categories for a venue while adding a venue.

**venue.rb**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :venues

end
```

**Join Table**

```
create_table "categories_venues", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "category_id", null: true
  t.integer "venue_id",    null: true
end

add_index :categories_venues, ["category_id", "venue_id"]
```

Most of the examples online show how to create the models from with another. I am not able to figure out how to have a multi select option where the user can select one or more categories and save it automatically.

Do i need to use `builder` in the controller? and add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?

Am new to Rails and been trying to search and read through the docs as well.

**Controller**

```
  def new
    @venue = Venue.new

    @categories = Category.all.order('name ASC')
    @countries = Country.all.order('name ASC').limit(25)
    @regions = Region.all.order('name ASC').limit(25)
    @cities = City.all.order('name ASC').limit(25)

    #render plain: @categories.inspect

  end
```

**View**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :parent_id, "Categories:<span class='mandatory'>*</span>".html_safe,:class => 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, @categories, :id, :name, { :prompt => true }, { :class => 'select-search', :selected => params[:user_id], :data => { :placeholder => 'Please Choose' } }) %>
      <%= show_errors(@venue, :category_ids).html_safe %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem was that he wasn't creating the relationships well. We've fixed it with this small changes:

```
def category_ids
  params.permit(category_ids: [])
end

def venue_params
   #removed category_ids from permit
end

def create
   @venue = Venue.new(venue_params)
   if @venue.save
     category_ids.each {|id| @venue.categories << Category.find(id)}
   # rest of the code
end
```

And for the update:

```
def update
   @venue = venue.find(params[:id])
   if @venue.update(venue_params)
      @venue.categories.delete_all
      category_ids.each {|id| @venue.categories << Category.find(id) }
```

Comment: is 'through' for has_many? when i assign a habtm with the naming conventions i dont think i need to do that right?

Comment: As long as the relation is through a join table you have to tell rails that with the :through

Comment: okay thanks. in the view i am collecting all the categories and passing it to :category_ids but when i try to submit and save it says it expects an array but received a string.

Comment: Check the form helpers documentation and if the problem stills paste the form and the params request,

Comment: what you post from the docs is only if i have additional columns. but i dont have it in this case. its just the joining IDs. i have posted the Form in my question.

Comment: Added an small guide.

Comment: will try that out. thanks a lot. when do we use a has_and_belongs_many in that case

Comment: I've always used this one. But I think that you can use both. Read this doc:http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Comment: can u elaborate the part after the build for the multi select. i tried going through the articles but not able to get it to work. since my categories are pre populated. can i just call @cat = Categories.all and then use that to populate the select. i am not able to figure out what to name the select box that will hold the values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56038/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-harsha-m-v).

Comment: the chat doenst seem to be loading in my browser. one sec will try to load in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the categories

```
= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][]", category.id, @product.categories.include?(category)
```

Substitute venue for product.

The key here is the naming of the form element...

If you want to do a multi select you can use a select ... Name it accordingly...
Venue[category_ids][] and you would have to set it up to allow multi select .. I think your models are set correctly by the way..

Sorry in on a mobile so code is not being formatted

Comment: when i try to name the multiselect its giving me error. can u tell me how to name this <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, @categories, :id, :name, { :prompt => true }, { :class => 'select-search', :selected => params[:user_id], :data => { :placeholder => 'Please Choose' } }) %>